# Docker node service return ECONNRESET network error when running npm install in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I have set up a simple laravel application using docker-compose.

Everything works fine, aside from node service.

When I run `docker-compose run --rm node npm install` in the project folder I receive the following error after the command works for some time
[image]

Also here is my docker-compose.yml file

version: "3.7"

services:
app:
build:
args:
user: delll
uid: 1000
context: ./
dockerfile: Dockerfile
image: landing-app
restart: unless-stopped
working_dir: /var/www/
volumes:
- ./:/var/www
networks:
- landing

```
nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
    - 8000:80
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
    - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
    - landing

node:
    image: node:15.5-alpine3.10
    working_dir: /assets
    volumes: 
        - ./:/assets
    command: "npm run watch" 

db:
    image: mysql:8
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
    networks:
        - landing
```

networks:
landing:
driver: bridge

Comment: Please don't paste screen shots of terminal windows; include the actual text of the error message.  It looks like it says "This is a problem related to network connectivity", which suggests it's not really a programming problem.  Why not just directly run `npm install` and `npm run watch` from the host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI After facing the same issue and looking at DOZENS of posts including this one (whose solution seems mighty complicated) what worked was a simple proxy config to be passed to npm itself.
This fixed it during the docker build process. All I had to do was add these lines to my Dockerfile BEFORE running the npm install command :-

`RUN npm config set http-proxy http://<my company proxy>:8099`

`RUN npm config set https-proxy http://<my company proxy>:8099`